# How can I access one agent delay block within another agent in AnyLogic?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

As depicted in the image below, I have an 'if' condition where I intend to check the `delay.size` property, which resides in another agent named Car. How can I access the `delay` block's 'size' property of the Car agent within this agent?

[image]

Comment: Well where is your DemandPoints agent? If you can reach the Car agent from there, then you can also reach the delay block inside. See the help: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html

Comment: Learn about OOP in AnyLogic, specifically "where am I and how do I get to", see https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to